# Want to execute having clause on conditional

Tags: sql

I think I am over-complicating this, but I have a table of users and a table of programs.  users are tied to 1 or more programs, and I want to lock out all users who don't belong to any  programs with an expiration date later than `01-01-2014`:

```
TABLE Users
UserId INT PKEY
Locked BIT

TABLE Programs
ProgramId INT PKEY
UserId INT FKEY => Users.UserId
ExpirationDate DATETIME
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.Locked = 1
FROM Users u
JOIN Programs p ON u.UserId = p.ProgramId
HAVING COUNT(p.ExpirationDate >= '01-01-2014') = 0
GROUP BY u.UserId
```

But obviously the `HAVING` clause is malformed.  I think this is something simple that I'm just overlooking, but how can I update only users with no programs that expire beyond the first of January of this year?  Preferably without using a sub-select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE users
SET Locked = 1
FROM Users
WHERE userid NOT IN (
        SELECT userid
        FROM Users u
        INNER JOIN Programs p ON u.UserId = p.ProgramId
        WHERE p.ExpirationDate >= '01-01-2014'
        )
```

Or to use a cte try the below

```
; WITH ToUpdate
AS (
    SELECT Userid
        ,locked
    FROM Users u
    LEFT JOIN Programs p ON u.UserId = p.ProgramId
    GROUP BY u.UserId, u.locked
    HAVING ISNULL(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN p.ExpirationDate >= '01-01-2014'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END),0) = 0

    )
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Locked = 1
```

Comment: That works, is it possible to do this without a subselect though?

Comment: jokulmorder you can use a CTE: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Ah, good thinking, thanks!  I need to use those more often when it's appropriate.

Comment: @JamieA But you could easily get the CTE to return only the rows you want to update and it becomes a simple UPDATE statement using the CTE.

Comment: If you want to edit it to include that I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks jokulmorder, try the updated answer. Kudos @JonH for suggesting CTE

Comment: You can avoid the sum as well, just do the opposite, WHERE p.ExpirationDate < thedate

Comment: @jonh thinking about it, we need the sum, otherwise a user with a program ending after the date who also has a program ending before the data will still be locked out